# Material Dialogs Don't Work under Chrome on Some Machines

Tags: angular-material-8

Angular Material Dialogs have stopped working on my machine under Chrome. They have also stopped working on the web, so it's not a coding issue.

Instead of showing a dialog, any site that uses Angular Material dialogs just shows an empty transparent gray overlay. The dialogs still work OK under Edge. They were working OK last week.

I've rebooted several times, updated everything on my system, reinstalled Chrome, turned off graphics acceleration, removed all my Chrome extensions, and cleared my cache, checked memory usage, and looked in the system log for errors.

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

When I browse to this site and click the "Pick One" button I get a gray overlay and no dialog.

I'm just seeing a gray overlay. There are no messages in the console window.

Needless to say this has left me rather unnerved about the whole framework as this would be a total pain on a customer site.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation these dialogs do work Incognito mode. Clearing the cache still didn't work, but signing out of Chrome, *then clearing the cache and signing back in again fixed the problem. Perhaps this helps somebody.